# Using PHP to replace different numbers preceded by either MB or GB

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a site that displays strings like

```
"Requires 10MB data", 
"Requires 700MB data", 
"Requires 1.2GB data" etc.,
```

and I'm trying to find a way to bolden the **10MB** or **700MB** or **1.2GB** parts.

This would result in

```
"Requires <b>10MB</b> data", 
"Requires <b>700MB</b> data", 
"Requires <b>1.2GB</b> data" etc.,
```

I've abused Google for a while but have no idea what to actually search for.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm assuming this is without changing the display string to remove the "Requires" and "data" parts, correct?

Comment: @ChrisForrence - I was half asleep by the time I posted the question, and after reading it now I should have actually said that I'm trying to make the numbers bold without removing anything else.. like this - "Requires <b>10MB</b> data" or "Requires <b>700MB</b> data" .. any ideas?

Comment: Ah...I see what happened. Basically, when using Markdown, HTML tags get hidden (such as the crucial `<bold>` tag). If you want HTML tags to appear in your text, you need to surround them with tick marks (the key above Tab, to the left of the "1" key). That changed how your question was interpreted, unfortunately. But now you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to search and replace the MB/GB parts, you can use the [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) method:

```
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject);
```

Your method, then, would look like this.

```
$string = 'Requires 340MB of space.';
$string = preg_replace('/([0-9.]+[KMGT]B)/', '<b>$1</b>', $string);
echo $string; // Outputs "Requires <b>340MB</b> of space."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can this `preg_match` to remove number before GB/MB:

```
$replaced = preg_match('[0-9.]+[GM]B', $str, $m);
var_dump($m[0]);
```

#### Explanation:

```
[0-9.]+ match a single character present in the list below
Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible
0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
. the literal character .
[GM] match a single character present in the list below
GM a single character in the list GM literally (case sensitive)
B matches the character B literally (case sensitive)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you dont like regex or dont see the need to load a whole regex library for something this simple try:

```
$t = 'Requires 10MB data';

$t = str_replace( array('Requires ', ' data') , '', $t);
```

Should leave you just the 10Mb or 1.2GB part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm too simple but...

```
$str = str_replace('B data', 'B', str_replace('Requires ', $original_str);
```

Comment: Look up str_replace, it allows you to pass arrays rather than nest calls.